# Why theses two calls to map returns different value?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explains me why

`["23", "45", "67"].map(parseInt);` returns `[ 23, NaN, NaN ]`

but

`["23", "45", "67"].map((e) => parseInt(e));` returns `[ 23, 45, 67 ]`

?

Comment: What does `parseInt("45",1)` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`["23", "45", "67"].map(parseInt)` is basically:

```
["23", "45", "67"].map((e, i) => parseInt(e, i))
```

So, it is internally..

- For "23" `i` is `0`. Thus `parseInt('23', 0) // 23`
- For "45" `i` is `1`. Thus  `parseInt('45', 1) // NaN`
- For "67" `i` is `2`. Thus it `parseInt('67', 2) // NaN`

In this `["23", "45", "67"].map((e) => parseInt(e));`, default `radix` is `10`. So it gives you back `[23, 45, 67]`.

Read the [MDN Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Syntax#Description) to understand why in this case default `radix` is selected as `10`.